# Visio - Perpendicular Connectors on Activity Diagram

Tags: visio

How do I draw connections that bend at perpendicular (90 degrees) angles between states in an Activity Diagram in Microsoft Visio? I want these connections to adapt when I move the states, so simply drawing straight lines obviously is not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the adaptable connectors here. They are not the Activity Control Flow connections so you can't details additional properties, but it might help getting your Activity Diagram looking the way you want.

[image: Connectors in Visio]